# Angular 13 errors only show in main.js issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an issue in angular 13 in which I can't seem to see where my errors are because they are not showing the component the error comes from but only show that it comes from main.js. This is a very  confusing and makes it hard to solve issues.

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "resifia": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": false,
                "hidden": true,
                "vendor": true
              },
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "100kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
                "buildOptimizer": false,
  "optimization": false,
  "vendorChunk": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "resifia:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "resifia:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
                "browserTarget": "resifia:build:development"
              }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "resifia:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "resifia:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "resifia:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {
            "prerender": false,
            "ssr": false,
            "browserTarget": "urugo:build:production",
            "firebaseProject": "urugo-5781f",
            "firebaseHostingSite": "urugo-5781f"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "resifia"
}
```

Heres an image of the error.

[image]

Any ideas or help?

I've tried setting a development config but nothing has changes so far

Comment: Do you have source maps enabled in DevTools?

Comment: I do not have DevTools

Comment: The error is typical for a FormArray. I feel that it came from a component that iterate over an array instead iterate over the formArray.controls

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely an error that is located in the files that you created. Files such as main.js are files you really should not try to edit or modify in any way unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Also, errors that seem to appear in main.js are quite common, so you should ignore that and focus on the files you are working on. What you can do though, is to isolate segments of your code by commenting out lines of code and keep recompiling it until you see the error disappears.

Comment: I want to actually see where the error is in the component. I have no issues in main.js. The error does not show me where it is in the component. The error message is not clear. This was not an issue in angular 11

Comment: do a console.log(this.YourVariable, 'this is my error') then or you can just try updating to angular 15 as the error handling is now better, it will tell you exactly where in the component it is

Comment: @LuigiWoodhouse even though that helps in easy scenarios, that is awful way to debug code.